# How do I pass a variable/literal for a value in styled components?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I always use props as it's the basic way for managing different use cases, but I'm trying to change border color **during the focus state** of a styled input (is it possible to assign props to a focus state?).

I'm familiar with using props but even within the styled component, I'm not able to assign to a variable. i can't say `{props => props.focused ? accentCol : null}`. The only way I've been able to assign variables has been through inline styles. However, afaik there's no way to access focus state through inline styles :/

```
const accentCol = `{some redux function which retrieves different colors in different scenarios`

const styledInput = styled.input`
  background: #181a1a;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  &::placeholder {
  }
  &:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    border: solid 2px accentCol !important;
  }
`
```

how do I assign border color to a variable?

Comment: Did you read the docs? Something not clear? Passing props its the basic usage of styled components. https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props

Comment: i'm familiar with using props but even within the styled component I'm not able to assign to a variable. i can't say `{props => props.focused ? accentCol : null}`. The only way I've been able to assign to variables has been through inline styles. However, afaik there's no way to access focus state through inline styles, hence why I'm asking on stack overflow :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
interface IProps {
  focus: string,
}

const variantsfocus = {
  primary: 'solid 2px accentCol',
};

const StyledInput = styled.input<IProps>`
  background: #181a1a;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  &::placeholder {
  }
  &:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    border: ${props => variantsfocus[props.focus]};
  }
`
```

I hope this would be helpful, you have to pass the prop in the component like

```
<StyledInput focus="primary" />
```

[This link may be helpful also](https://blog.devgenius.io/using-styled-components-and-props-with-typescript-react-a3c32a496f47).

Answer (score 0):

Following the docs explanation:

```
const StyledInput = styled.input`
  &:focus {
    outline: none;
    border: solid 2px ${(props) => props.focusBorder};
  }
`;

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <StyledInput focusBorder="red" />
      <StyledInput focusBorder="blue" />
    </>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-focus-etf4pd

Comment: Could you please edit this for typescript? it's giving me a `No overload matches this call` error